# How to pass variable from pipeline into dataflow destination dataset

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have created variable in a pipeline, next I pass it to copy activity and then I used it to build path in a dataflow so I am able to pass that variable into dataflow source dataset, but for some reason Iam not able to pass it into dataflow destination dataset
I have created same parameters in destination as in the source but destinations dataset is not picking it,not sure why when source dataset is having it

Comment: It would be helpful if you could you post some screenshots.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass variable from pipeline into dataflow destination dataset.

To pass pipeline variable to the destination dataset in dataflow create destination dataset with parameters and pass that parameter to path values.

Here I have this destination dataset. In that dataset under `Parameters` created 3 parameters.

[image]

Then pass that dataset parameters to the respective path under `Connection` from dynamic expressions.

[image]

After this go to your pipeline under Data flow `settings` you will see Source and sink parameters par your pipeline variable as value to the respective parameter.

[image]

If still not working unselect the data flow and select it again it will refresh the dataflow to take all values.